# PHP change date after x hours

Tags: php, date

In my code I am successful to display current date but my requirement is to show next day date after `3` hours e.g. `2017-08-17 20:00:00` the next date will be `2017-08-18` but it will show next date after spending 3 hours i.e. `2017-08-18 03:00:00` until that it remain show the old date.

I am able to add `3` hours to current date/time but I don't know how to show it after 3rd hour of the next date. Here is my code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time_add = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours'));
$time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $time_now;
?>
```

Comment: What are you doing with `$time_add`? You're assigning it but not echoing it or doing anything else with it

Comment: $time-add and $time_now have no relation .

Comment: What does it mean: " I don't know how to show it after 3rd hour of the next date" ?

Comment: @Andy i want to print `$time_now` after `(date('H') > 3)` but dont know how it works

Comment: Rtra could you please explain better. You need a different output if the hour of the date is less than 3?

Comment: @ednincer yes you're right but this has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours'));`

The problem with your code is that you were assigning this to a variable called `$time_add` but then doing nothing with it.

If you want to print the **current** date/time after it, just use it without `+3 hours`:

`echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: it works but I want to show it after spending 3 hours of like `if (date('H') > 3) { .. }`

Comment: But that will never be the case. Because every time the script is executed it adds 3 hours on to the current date/time. It will always be ahead of the current time so never be a satisfiable condition.